# Git uses wrong subkey for signing commits with GPG key

Tags: git, gnupg

I have an issue with git and signing commits with GPG key.

I have a master key (used for certification only). I've created two subkeys (only for signing) per computer. I've added public key to Github, configured git by using `user.signingKey` configuration option.

The issue is that git seems to be ignoring the configuration option and uses the newest subkey all the time (the latest on the list `gpg --list-secret-keys EMAIL`).

I've checked it on two environments, same issue. I'm using the following git version: `git version 2.15.1`

Any clues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use a specific subkey, KEYID must be appended with `!`. So the configuration should look like the following:

```
[user]
    name = Andrzej Ośmiałowski
    email = me@osmialowski.net
    signingKey = KEYID!
```

Many thanks to **Todd Zullinger** to provide the solution on Git mailing list.

Comment: does not work for me. git continues to complain. But normal gpg signing works well.

Comment: I found a solution. The Problem was git using gpg 1.x instead of using gpg2 which i use for managing keys.

Comment: Great, this fixes the issue I was having too, but I'm failing to find any additional details on why this is happening, or which version might be causing this.
It has started happening for me with 

git version 2.41.0

gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.20

libgcrypt 1.8.5

It was not happening with versions 

git version 2.36.1

gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22

libgcrypt 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

The [git commit man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) describes:

> -S[]
>   --gpg-sign[=]
>   GPG-sign commits. The keyid argument is optional and defaults to the **committer identity**; if specified, it must be stuck to the option without a space.

Would it help to always specify the sign key on `git commit`?`

It could be an issue on the git suite (Can you check on their issue tracker?

EDIT: Also maybe [this](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-an-email-with-your-gpg-key/) is worth a try.

Comment: This is something definitely wrong, because specifying the keyid with `--gpg-sign=KEYID` does not work either;